# java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\firemonitor\build\web\images\2.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, file, file-io, filenotfoundexception

i have a error while running java project in netbeans
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\firemonitor\build\web\images\2.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)
this is a image processing project i think their is problem in ij.jar or comm.jar file

is their is any file comm.jar-1

Comment: Well `FileNotFoundException` means, hmm... file not found under the path you have specifyed... and what is `ij.jar` or `comm.jar` in the first place?

Comment: open web browser and put this `file:///C:/firemonitor/build/web/images/2.jpg` and write what you can see

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You may need to show us some of the code in question before anyone will be able to adequately help. It's good practice to edit any relevant code into the question and perhaps add the Stack Trace, and then people will really be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

"\" can't used as the file seperator.Because it is the starting if escape characteres.replace it with double "\" or "/"